# JQuery css() effect reversed unless I call alert('time waste') beforehand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The code segment is running in a plugin method, ie `$.fn.insideThisMethod()` that is called on page load. Inside the method it makes a call to

`$obj.css('height',$(window).height());`

works fine in Chrome. IE9 however I experience the following: On page load I can see for a split second (while the jquery has yet to be fired) the background of the `$obj` appear. So far so good. Then when the jquery code is run on page load another object in the background appears in place of it, ie the `$obj` disappears for some reason. The only way to prevent this is to put an `alert('whatever');` into the jquery code before the above call to `$obj.css()` is made. In that case the `$obj` stays where it's supposed to on screen, doesn't disappear and everything is fine. Note if I put an alert in after the call to `$obj.css()`, `$obj` will still disappear from view after clicking ok.

I know this is vague but putting it up here in case this might be a known error for jquery noobs to run into and somehow is easy to correct.

I'm guessing it's something to do with it running when the browser loads, possibly a resource is not quite ready yet that is ready once the alert box has been dismissed.

edit: tried wrapping the above in `$(document).ready(function(){})`; but no change to behaviour.

Comment: If I don't sort it out on my own I'll have to try to. It's a big script...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$obj.css('height',$(window).height() + 'px');
```

Or alternatively:

```
$obj.height($(window).height());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem you are not able to find window height. try to alert window height

if window height is zero then try to run your code at window.load instread of document ready

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    $obj=$("SOME_SELECTOR");
    $obj.css('height',$(window).height()+'px')
  })
```

if window height is coming correctly then

sometime applying style doesn't force browser to render the page. in this kind of cases it has to do with positioning of any of the parent elements or height width of the some elements. but i found it very difficult to debug whenever happens.

The work around is add or remove class on the element or parent element or at last body.

so try 1 followings 1 by 1

```
$obj.css('height',$(window).height() +'px' ).addClass("dummyCalss").removeClass("dummyCalss");

or 

$obj.css('height',$(window).height() +'px' ).parenet().addClass("dummyCalss").removeClass("dummyCalss");

or

$obj.css('height',$(window).height() +'px' );
$("body").addClass("dummyCalss").removeClass("dummyCalss");
```

Comment: It definitely has access to the window height as it appears in alert and is used prior successfully anyway. Tried your workaround too but no effect unfortunately.

Comment: In this case you must provide a sample link or some code sample. I think there is something else setting height to zero or auto or some other style property applied. Try to use ie developer tool bar and see whats the element's style when it disapreased.